# Recover Encrypted String With Python - Passphrase, Salt, and Source Code Known

Tags: python, kotlin, cryptography

I have some source code in Kotlin that I only partially understand. I know a little bit of Python so I'm looking to recreate the decrypt function.

I have an encrypted string that I want to recover, and the original passphrase and salt too.

Here is the source ([from here, with constants, encrypt function etc](https://github.com/nightscout/AndroidAPS/blob/23207a275f97d1db1d993eae5122282920092602/core/src/main/java/info/nightscout/androidaps/utils/CryptoUtil.kt)):

```
fun decrypt(passPhrase: String, salt: ByteArray, encryptedData: String): String? {
        val iv: ByteArray?
        val encrypted: ByteArray?
        return try {
            lastException = null
            val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.decode(encryptedData))
            val ivLength = byteBuffer.get().toInt()
            iv = ByteArray(ivLength)
            byteBuffer[iv]
            encrypted = ByteArray(byteBuffer.remaining())
            byteBuffer[encrypted]
            val cipherDec: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
            cipherDec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, prepCipherKey(passPhrase, salt), GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv))
            val dec = cipherDec.doFinal(encrypted)
            String(dec)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            lastException = e
            aapsLogger.error("Decryption failed due to technical exception: $e")
            null
        }
    }
```

Here is my attempt simplified (I get incorrect padding when using the inputs I have):

```
def generate_key(password, salt, iterations):
    assert iterations > 0
    key = base64.b64decode(password + salt)
    for i in range(iterations):
        key = hashlib.sha256(key).digest()
    return key


def decrypt(ciphertext, password):
    salt = 'XXXXXXXetc'
    key = generate_key(password, salt, NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
    plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext, cipher)
    return plaintext
```

Edit:

Here is some test data, with passphrase `1234`

```
{
  "format": "aaps_encrypted",
  "metadata": {
    "device_name": "Galaxy S8 SE",
    "created_at": "2022-04-19T19:58:17.338Z",
    "aaps_version": "3.0.0.1",
    "aaps_flavour": "full",
    "device_model": "samsung SM-G950F (dreamlte)"
  },
  "security": {
    "file_hash": "96cf809f37eb46d0eb837511bae539b5fadd424e74d3e6eedaa4ceb2fdac07d8",
    "algorithm": "v1",
    "salt": "4030cc7f15e5f7bf830543270ced2b7c8b24237c53ce95382b232df69c594353",
    "content_hash": "197510b071e3e592c43301e77c997400048641e77275a02ebd41a58213e90c61"
  },
  "content": "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"
}
```

Comment: That's not actually Java.

Comment: Oh right. It's Kotlin! Will update. Made the mother of all assumptions because it's an Android app. Shows how much I know about Java.

Comment: I deleted my answer. The discussion has shown that you don't ask for a port of the `decrypt()` method, but rather want to know why your *particular* ciphertext cannot be decrypted. However, you don't provide the information needed to answer this question, especially the test data for a repro is missing. I therefore vote to close this question. Please complete any information needed to answer.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I really appreciated your answer. I had to go to bed as it was later where I'm from. I'll continue to troubleshoot today. I'm learning about new concepts and providing test data is difficult without showing my whole config file (the encrypted string is my mobile app config file in a bigger json doc).

Comment: I said on the comment of your answer I would work to get some test data. I'll do that today by installing the app on a burner phone, generating a generic (uncompromising) preferences file. I'll post that shortly.

Comment: @Topaco text/example data added

Comment: The posted data can be decrypted for me with both the Kotlin and the Python code. Thus, the Python code seems to work, so I undeleted my answer. I don't know why the decryption fails for you. You may have handled the salt improperly, this needs to be hex decoded. The \-characters in the Base64 string are of course wrong and I removed them in my answer (which however is actually not necessary, because `base64.b64decode()` automatically discards invalid characters).

Comment: Not sure how the backslashes get in there. The file is as generated. But I'm just glad it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [encrypting with the Kotlin code](https://github.com/nightscout/AndroidAPS/blob/23207a275f97d1db1d993eae5122282920092602/core/src/main/java/info/nightscout/androidaps/utils/CryptoUtil.kt#L63), the following data is concatenated at the end:

- Size of the nonce
- nonce
- ciphertext/tag

When decrypting with the Python code, this data must be separated.
Note that Kotlin/Java returns as ciphertext the concatenation of actual ciphertext and tag. These two parts must also be separated, since Python processes both separately.

In addition, PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA1 is used as the [key derivation in the Kotlin code](https://github.com/nightscout/AndroidAPS/blob/23207a275f97d1db1d993eae5122282920092602/core/src/main/java/info/nightscout/androidaps/utils/CryptoUtil.kt#L50). This algorithm must also be used for decryption with the Python code.

A possible implementation in Python is:

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Hash import SHA1
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

AES_KEY_SIZE_BIT = 256
TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128
PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 50000 

def decrypt(passphrase, salt, ciphertext):

  # Separation
  ciphertextBytes = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
  ivSize = int.from_bytes(ciphertextBytes[:1], "big")      
  iv = ciphertextBytes[1:1+ivSize]
  actualCiphertext = ciphertextBytes[1+ivSize:-TAG_LENGTH_BIT//8]
  tag = ciphertextBytes[-TAG_LENGTH_BIT//8:]

  # Key derivation
  key = PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, AES_KEY_SIZE_BIT//8, count=PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,  hmac_hash_module=SHA1)

  # Decryption
  cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
  decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(actualCiphertext, tag)
  return decrypted

passphrase = "1234".encode('utf-8')
salt = bytes.fromhex("4030cc7f15e5f7bf830543270ced2b7c8b24237c53ce95382b232df69c594353")
ciphertext = "DKQDMzcfTQdd59fKSN5s3pmcbs+nK4fS6VUt0+sfWDolkrUqfq33HT82GOpUwCpCtHH0zwY2plw8ZEgv1a4I/OjDQeueAyVL8NZUiNKWPdtUwSxbfiAuP6P61H1X9iGIAvhuvR+uyy2l/DNyWqIox2tvcNGXqt3og2mFojiqryB+tKfia8dO7bpph/8q3/NGtJajijqTPNCcjLid8N0yivEXKSXaceL9qdGGZNoMGmIGMhrlrS8JBKOfRvFkE7hdat6D8uaF4iyxfuLGY210oDenf2V+GcT5XBWv8nr1NKWaQTJOLx6A2QKZM/9xKck0fl04PCFFz+d0x+Y3HgiecFrU3uCWKSL901OCUIlDdOiR7U1Ik1BJFfRzZMaB8qLU7uyc9SNzXs55u3Xm2yD14Fa44jhQKkXI/DplqYl4M8wgSL7M2oCqNIMI4VpRpRF9apGRcdzVCjwnOWk3mBQkOUn/etITu2kRMB8QZqvxXJtW40ZRjmqNXH7/xWV+jDr+3QnmdvqVl7YvityxfPmTTnJdQpUYvV8SbKR2kclidhZ9pTF14yndejNrZru5IE5D7a8vuiydkL6vcAchM9ts3MBv/lg0Bu5y8H5+DCp8lwVBZDgPnjH1CpfNtk/nYTJnlkkmRdjozZeqjrC8J/+saRqizgXFqblVXY2A3Z0gF9iVjbGZywsabns1vUuYalqaXKW9U8sNZvs3S0/ngRC25Rgo6AQdloqKr4PLeCEO18jq/Vh+Vky8MoAZXS/xmCyFdAn+EDLCdhKEYTA9Ynl+pRTGAwtS9HLgNq36AohlKQm2vuRP1dchaelzL5tycHuNQq6zqUqh+4j0dw2vd7P8ZRvE3m5wNnOLC7lugpddxnbrwI/j1Pu9aPlHHZWTy9dKW01IThVC9FWJqnhEhGao19FDXBEAjOUh70o2YIDb3d8oEDLMJX5Weaaoh9itMVLkafwmYx3YhqZqZ+38RykuL7x36aCksefL/YtphPJkxwPgny2IDM6948uNUg3jUCem7ZwxHTWhgsIxI00PNo2D1ZWAOdk8HPy+gRaJ/rXsNvo0ErW2CD4gkKT8cvwkRJ2WH+ovcVrcMFO1Ns7a8VdksjuMZhCWa8rzl6efRznT7FkXrKJSmUG5WkLQbPlSirMN2YK2R111qm7hbxvcTMFvGIh6ZZDHdDaaWMi7M3nHRT8AzlTiap1arnTCpSqtMVndB4Gu6i/fNOFiV+3iXFfDUJsgvcGBDHsOQZ3lCdkHcCz5H1UB8D0tqqPHKt/TAAwz/Ew5axshAmiCuKqC+EiTTHkHKd1e5uCF5kRXJWxlzlGNWYJmVZOkPfDpV0mX81Nc9RGgAKnzZ9v/kHvzKsCjXyPbgzXBuYB+FqaaP8CNNlyrKuTObqndUnCPIbIpBEtMf7auI2n5ME78KXd+fPX1PvCYx3z4Z6FwZVBNtfTiIQgK4obNaPG40ysdcSGonKSDEVNEUDlZOZWTdNxGfXa5XfmsYN+qw3v1+Sd2FDKjlP1BZPOmsCNEWXBrnqLsuoHnGv20che/spEsS8aTQ4pWCerb4f7o13b303cTbSyQaC0AohH9UfjdXS19pkdHQySV2EXTLfcvfPPX+E39aZG4BiKZ86jbmUQNjhgpoFupK9VUa7ZEEwQfhUOrTvZr+zcwV0fJcD9FaaEcVLs1kez7TRhS/p8rBUpSvoLa5KSEfquHbQq0WUr/bSiX0hXVGY0h6MooZ8z/HCFzzBHhHFZfRfsEbr1F9cJp7cn8MuqDuIH3GJ+6wW8JAb/ftk/BHMtfSvT/TWxmldn+Z5GQwGODJ5nGQTzsFmOJszSoVubVfuEJQ94SMHAB0tULDHhIFDknDgDjEY3VuNQ51ZC8nGas4XuohLTMeZ6cmJJmTnvPYDFb0RlbVrG7TVq7VaoZNIx9tTUhmAaSvbiiDc9pHGbiWAb5oe9dpGWjPDi5kayrckDjWkImy3jJLEV+s9Dtz5R621+GzkQYw0KTKDEaqQtVkWXPP+8do2PyRn+zh5MOpV7CxVKbjs19vR2gcC2DE9Ra/naK+cvKiwLnzmZEleBCCKsB5+9LJzHvhPrpbaFczKxDi/A9LAwCFawGjsS6hF58tI2FpZoOw/FacP1wb8V6sp97dCZjRH14ECMp24AuTfnmbwXmabT5/zJUyDZoGCd7NONM0lOFBDFmKn+kwo/gyB5Sy/YFFVEeTEfzL+49tPfphA/SmbeyCop51ln8BeIOTTpdAwhSNpyU2YzUB845nN6I+/9QUO7ErkHBEhbAbwbVAiLev0dkw9J+2V4tZEMVzhoJrV5QjBiu+wvGj0pBUhmSXOUhfyqnlp3XK6FU7M63MWzRlkZarW7FFHcGdhnArqQ9st/ETdVXGpVR3ZGPxeh0C9ycjUpPKtRxEuNf93JGf99UPxou83zoL3sfEkxfWAbDB0eW2WoNZveuPaLwN3fGEgQaxglEXlM/L9CaihvCZocseWHtpoBS1HjdHj7gGrRF/DPOudS8dvu/mWmK4IaUKIErYZoBnjopDmtpzqoNENjTNkhRvp3ojxg/DgXsos3t7RxORC07T0SC/SjUo6veEk5COlLENb49PozZbVIL6YECXp1xJxbf/QCFiXosA+S34ERwSwkJGYGhaPY42XJUODplYecy22FKjg2HN/bvR213IQt9ctmZN5JB3wC8Fmyi5faxf2sl9VV3aM7ekpr3tyj7ATAvyRMl1UlnAz30ZO7GGhGhQbxYpe5SU20dpcVfC+U3VQzrsGHW5f6OaI3GJpM5PVL98bK+CfXEvC9acmPyH0AVHPWvYPEih81r2Ek4n2T6evtgrvixbRBGDTr24hB+27u29GEsZnqoL9vPx7xJeJ1WYYKYerVg+t2GiVgEmn3XOFt3CkrSrp144HrWo0ZgAipTQ8BHVJ45r5WsojRLKrazpJMYLnFBSx4iokhtODb9dv0Tum+wZ2zUIhsXDMBbAsjSDhJtrQLwuCoLzaz7o5BGinq9fIJks7uVZ5dUGe5dMJux8zNwujPVP9fuwsmmP6ObbGsG4MEhgyVoSpV39v8l7gyrulLp3D1fxbtNmZ9JolHFNtGTrkbouFjEnKn8B4iE4ofLGcuWGBnw/zVSerFdMO8/I4FaofLFQCLmx92s/ROBXuycYJ4Isa4flJAwWK8SKIFpGWQg/FfLkij611I+1i5m8wHX2XHcm5veA4ZcdcfhzqtywP8onLia0KZdZMrRRwa4oz6wumV3m56tyS/zeEiPri9iqitZnlVwEtHCh/jTQwfUykbMiidVficpqPGi5k8D0iUTJ5FtFSQkVOpK9KOX7CgO/z6958d/ZA9SJ1XZumuTBDfFmOwI3nkOIbThjGfvs7OlHyxP6K6k3Jkygt8bLUIshJHwLOPRlFlNhZLN9mcIYRhdVMJr0ZODLjdTLB94gLYUTffsLc27JHVeBEWWtDBr8IEc3Oq7cqPZpbSTM1/5pjlxRXYIUIlgeAbUMeg/yHof6NyPpzjO1bxhj1YM4qmnWL34f82eO/3sim5GcT56hm5pkFeF2vKs+JKbVNYwaMOYhcuQBCXT+Ta+hqCjColVQrJf9twy1k+aGkJrMBaKelIYaWprKGennWL/hVQwEgOR28426euRTHdgWPsQqe46hy1FabEjiWgRYsSiIwKHszpKXEyy760BvJqeJhRC4FFDooD8grnjuoDpnK8brUhlwWlmpPDSbm02eZSPxT54zBkti5u/EONG2Dj3EtQ6jaQ29CvxVkIHPwapyTWBMO3d4dGJ0pfhYVHLwxtd02I8eVBU471jv57cU/P4ypYGLMt3q14MMfKVTKqSbE0lM0mVt1wPgRTolIsAbRJYdDuwrQXxFM0mo1SXjkAwdoXxlYwBnLT6rsLwQpI0VrkESygdFjuWrc/1IDbUkoy99nlC7YmQ9drvR6h7Jhol2LuQPche+fnIy4rzx6XD6K1GFwa5Rii/pBCvJ4AH9z3EwKhvL1Q0U1SjUiKTv69OSWfQKmjFLehtRrXx8odVFiYafxhfsskstPDkbdElT5SvLUOZOrqqdHq78LJuLC7GBRd1OPTG0VpokmSGNigRAwV+ZvlY8D/Xqlyc92FCnl9auQGsfwmcvcgiM74YcRTKFfH4sHmIPgWxBH3/oX5S9fn40hOORHMpQwqpdD+IvMiVS1dgKfThNT39JaMu441THkPH9ijYLJdlUv+SVtiMqnk+rZXgNsSeWSkhduGKs22wXceFM1CWIZtlvM6VL/n8tHaOF0hk1F5GJ1kSbAG97YG8dRTU9XvcOzyStCYw1yDGH0Wo0V8iLyPefBNbueFpPcnkQ9sAt9fhDx+v4XJ6X9Vq0iNvGbZQWo8wZghAOjMPNiopJUuL4hky4rXxrp0o5uCtNJSvmgs8FUUD8Wjn5/9ZMA4EXNvmNBxSrpifiwWx+Hrq9tUD22uFb/8Y5BWHjSNUOeed1QG9upxKf6FXPohfDVd1Y7ECNh7J12yvrFkxo+PiUDlyC47OKzc4NlYZMZLLA4udHln4aAXEnwRm6tmK0tKbbTWkjsgWrQChT/Soxv4a/vqjqvwLzm1grr2iaYSYAOMRDMwRse/h9L913RKI9+IbmRfToxgTcrSqIhBDM99H+PARRIBZtf75dEOn4yGBqEMyroPgR0mjs2dPslMOntIPYbLAUoAKydpc0FNbvmpmaX5n0N1dFB3UJZOFYKP+A5nx8kYWsKhG+nfjvMVPF7eFW7YksQfWqT8xka33ySfWhdPbtbyNWXJxKUCZSzzorc4qHQuo5GQCO3Tu/V4TTfNENcxgE3VZDQ0qUPix4ShIx5WDn7uYtj8oP+jWuqbwu+blV45w/u8/yAbR5HWDfY5n3ce3yeqPlaX50jZ5iBWdY27LtYwy+R79cgxL+x/hMMmftKoz1e5UL33JJ+Aq+clbjUSKkSK7lpuJDhCUb2MXi0jy2KkyHfP5vPcdcuqLCwc/UPRrxjsYfIQDzryGHXbX2RoFPINnZU0uqOm2YuHz9+9zEX1ahpTKTx0y2j7OdsD2PBAJs1a8ip9j4Xx+7ZNM6Ngqvsm2cAjurtcp52yCkIuDOoVU6t5OBwCbm6SRQswT1oayjEgbUn/Kn6+oXDrx9Vc4G/hZk95kK1Ygu6Sh1PEeftTNXVfYkpfjRgb0UQDPpupDL83cEKC+WhSp/3S2sMo8tUtENPX9EXO+nLEy6XZEA1FpalN6vT4ThMYUximQEGXb/fYerhaC353Ht/f5Dr56KGuwDPCSpL4yJJ6BloU2qgxwZiIHp8IM86k1bnMuCnY3KZltvPcXXJ6E5sDQB0Z1BLnnSnLKuAKeX6ulJ5noBkTzZe4rQwHF5cXNQx9pX6TFKxjSiu9qAB9fQYrm6Faj8FqbTVhACKSXHw7kj3DOeavgE28wyj9pO/jfGfwV8sP3xOH1r4pM6CbuJavgXticH0X9ho6VyrRrsy74XZp1AI6FBHP6iIdA/b7w7il8Vl7TsaZyf+xbYtCM1hIcsgCUVo50tYG3CoL+5kOjfzViZnxlJZhEGqZssp+/kOb7Ty2ZoS0ZewjqRwOesRdEFM2ABy43qLuT7C1ulOJgYxKkAh4leb3vd0HYIXXTEkbfxrhHQ9j2dB3by6OyPbPgw8dVojeSAL/7/zaJoJdApKfeiV8BCHgsNdrdoVonOH4an0SD3YVuB5Yz81Z2C43WEJIUBITL/RVnVLIGOxVmEWHD4FkwQPgmUS770Z8rqq2sZRUIGgYgKSeAGkslE4itJUQ+/LeFwbK3WYaVa8iT4Rd74goc7Dm39h54qZ6dgel0CqgvzAngw2NmTP3aETa/Co+eMwNyCLP+QxGEzcnqgcs63YQyqrtG4pVhQg5cMkQbRpqsytHPjg2mS+fBSAD1sXF5lrThlg6skL70o4H36abbAjOST/ThvJ/hViFb6lCD7w+iXDuOa0+p3sn4yhgMIqcRwKjcIxx5GsGNNSJDKWWJn7zxdT525gwSh7rf/aGVI9PNUhlXC0bdcHQ4UjIkqSa5MQbapiDDhg1PEqDlBa0v6vqSIdDAKaxWVZNYk0Msr3cNwaAYyQfdYVCrd6CN0bFIeOWOng6klQhTYxkhmrsogCXCsMLDFaBr/IbfQSMfwtsYiM9Jtcn18QjfumXucfKL/F0rP0D3FKOD72idANPCy+73lYAxGSDLVmT4wmsGCEcmAtrJHCauHn65T+lSZ5d8LGFbU4P3fzP2i0+vDfPh74/BOpx3rPgJ24chryugVZ3LRgCYrphkiiz7u+cAAsUUmcb3/9Oy8hRdqMYIW+d8bvLygwdt/5BjGALaF4l6kr+BuC3Zdfm3VpNgSd0yneWc81sHJVY+NTGGH6r0UEGlNOaXfv3EgCVKFIVVxQ7sdQZMlVsh/st7NET6aPvEALHnfcC1LxmnBq4eDHNPD9Dkf2BPedenQM+nl1kzvFAn3wmRknOkW5R1yNn/ytxx0HGmmR8Ice5wgZ4O1iiu6gYQIgfNh7iqZa6f9+uRR7OPx3G3F3FqU494Fz966O311NQWt0v9OsZcTCjdHJacQQAlrhj6ueuAjvzwPEONSf9K2l6TNYcFqw8GzppCc10C+R/q72nSInBhsDSTw3uxgP+acqC6vthAUi6ddQSsn1n8go5+hhZ/+BG1253M3k646Lzf3auMRmIpsm7+S1ILBZ0yoDTTh4c2+MeN2WhTaoyX2aA2SN3uNtLVEKeiZS6abtkp1VnoMP0j2IXlCkP+mii/oqche0vGbbTphq2UUANX7KnHbbO1cOZs9kQW7JKmCzXIb9qvqF3agB8R8x++FlXXvzaE0uEX2OLHI5n/jUgTEu+jktNbX/fXGZmPg+T0Fcy10N1LGumnMIf4DZ3LQpBMosI/Q7O1HfZslxjibux6HTQHMQq/3rJ4COnsYgLhHveFY05pCAKJIX+VXbW89zVgx/7FMBse7XVNAxZM4s+cIsPT8C4k12hqFoxBlMshjSOrF2IXLo3ha7jWl9+U4pK6wlCS3jxkIRjItzHss0Wsin9GuIAwsHo9mSpjVV88g93JOWNda7m9ClSSIBf6XVmcEVnWnRASOltW+8XKt66XviOlDQ9kc+s5j9UVKrh4EJ5y1+aVitzn95F/7YRZqwC3WKWLAnZcYkEw2Gowg9AUg5WCbpaKoWt/BLP+Rvklq+eWl8B9IthFtiWVVNR+j8yeJur/5jwgrEqmRysRi2gFWhrEtA+bnx9R1llfuYjHxxPjMjrtmPRwL5/ixnEajtuXEURjd227mnRXXuj7sYPcEb2bR18PgE4YTCkSNPlKN7tEg03TLMSk5BGtNJ4vRbfuGCWDdza7AXu8jBlF7Iz4Fr1XXwRRH1Cd4p1L6ChT/ODh1Co4nlsbj+ttjX4g8KcHBeZJnpCySC3crd5gRRSgl1Q+Ipj3Jn9RI04uSFYW+5ju9A3ssgn9Vc5IaxH++U2R4271sbTJ3hl95flFkPeqQLFBhl2BUs7MBzuaFnhzuD5aRiYln8bHzR0Xj2jGjUtTIenvf/ooVaYMENUwkY8hu8BYJQe183rSy7Y6dSvRZLvU7pOak2u1X0j3eDXEcFqbMpoNtJUSpGy9X4SoqD4KOcbOlP6b0y63tfZ2Y+tBQx/MF7RbuMJQN+sgD8iBltpJsYXgatTsvUw2l/G197UjG3FrZDROIZgnFCY/v4E4MUm8h2Vb7c7mU2WijpNMf2XL8Lk5533OltGoenaAU68qxrcSU2+xs/tNcLql+wwxNG1p7qC1lMRKzjfI88HdFIsaOmWPG62jzmkrZqeRp0Bp6ppeJu/IFdmus2ELqrmewgk4GSk7cm4qK/tE9xxYg0xD50exelnOuCzJyT5EyMa89pCHKKcr1M6rn90AD6fBq7AIRvb2GP44ADTNJrDG4ZjC+e13Flp7cf5LLWByYxe/ku4woR1g1DeJvWZnXOwuL5Z6OwmjM05MV9GvJIeIu0f469ameZlZp9n9EOE9qhqaS1hHqbLppPSnf5TEP5ElNjbv2jIWwPJbANa0CHFf1DqDM+Lh95CYgZTPozesNUasWH6/5drnxGhiJgqVTHM0aFFO4pEVfV49hltrzoxlOy3ZfDCDw/qYfpN9Ej9Nw8M+zjm4yWCbpjXuHa3BnZ2yBBT/Tsb2rqrOWSffaRMVak80px9OhdW/MSsYqIxu2F/1l1QlzyksAQfZREfJ5mDYMGIyD2uVjK66asosDtx2qCy3vsVdatB7sT24yiZHAfh1XfWqIv6pkJNuVYCQQNMj7Yl3fhMcDKn4sKox1W/1XPyGPYud+rZuAVzYLXgDihHRVRy3FnOgIylhSAXyQrnS3kDFIFreD3yC/vo98BHr/53/UgyJtVQEtqX2MKgZYx0qrCxGTqODZ2KL6t54bN9MTZP0kLD+uwqFx1aPwudrNffCU7/AVwte+4HjULcubQ3bsQcYYS9jDPo1upDYvvXmOlYj4dMCiO0Hvk1X1Wd6yS6Vz9SXFud3iHsfKdKcYMzSMTXX07tAnHBU0uYS5Cipbb3sKJHhmPouj+EjNpWr6D6XwPKKL4J/N5UzMWvjFXmeu7i7AzozgrMPhRrjyAv8hIDI9+4JiJpWQKbwWek0y4uUU9TnxvRqrvv5wgX+HFMAm36UqfUzFFbfAiULEgKPIF8jDwVp3fzZyWRtZYpc8xDOLAqM2H+rQOre7/6LNHNwHdDceY4vQ9rJ16UB+GwShFyHRmKqP2DPV7yJG11MOOAl6l1ugKGXWz22c3ulRowRP/qBeBarbgY="
print(decrypt(passphrase, salt, ciphertext).decode('utf-8')) # {"DisabledTo_basaltest":"0","DisabledTo_breadgrams":"0","DisabledTo_dia":"0","DisabledTo_exercise":"0","DisabledTo_exercise2":"0","DisabledTo_extendedcarbs":"0","DisabledTo_hypott":"0","DisabledTo_ic":"0","DisabledTo_insulin":"0","DisabledTo_iob":"0","DisabledTo_isf":"0","DisabledTo_noisycgm":"0","DisabledTo_nsclient":"0","DisabledTo_objectives":"0","DisabledTo_objectives2":"0","DisabledTo_otherMedicationWarning":"0","DisabledTo_prerequisites":"0","DisabledTo_prerequisites2":"0","DisabledTo_profileswitch":"0","DisabledTo_profileswitch2":"0","DisabledTo_profileswitch4":"0","DisabledTo_profileswitchtime":"0","DisabledTo_pumpdisconnect":"0","DisabledTo_sensitivity":"0","DisabledTo_troubleshooting":"0","DisabledTo_update":"0","DisabledTo_wrongcarbs":"0","DisabledTo_wronginsulin":"0","ExamTask_basaltest":"false","ExamTask_breadgrams":"false","ExamTask_dia":"false","ExamTask_exercise":"false","ExamTask_exercise2":"false","ExamTask_extendedcarbs":"false","ExamTask_hypott":"false","ExamTask_ic":"false","ExamTask_insulin":"false","ExamTask_iob":"false","ExamTask_isf":"false","ExamTask_noisycgm":"false","ExamTask_nsclient":"false","ExamTask_objectives":"false","ExamTask_objectives2":"false","ExamTask_otherMedicationWarning":"false","ExamTask_prerequisites":"false","ExamTask_prerequisites2":"false","ExamTask_profileswitch":"false","ExamTask_profileswitch2":"false","ExamTask_profileswitch4":"false","ExamTask_profileswitchtime":"false","ExamTask_pumpdisconnect":"false","ExamTask_sensitivity":"false","ExamTask_troubleshooting":"false","ExamTask_update":"false","ExamTask_wrongcarbs":"false","ExamTask_wronginsulin":"false","Monitor_MainActivity_resumed":"1650398254754","Monitor_MainActivity_start":"1650398048449","Monitor_MainActivity_total":"44111","Monitor_PreferencesActivity_resumed":"1650398069260","Monitor_PreferencesActivity_start":"1650398091955","Monitor_PreferencesActivity_total":"22695","Monitor_RequestDexcomPermissionActivity_resumed":"1650398253908","Monitor_RequestDexcomPermissionActivity_start":"1650398048510","Monitor_RequestDexcomPermissionActivity_total":"505","Monitor_SetupWizardActivity_resumed":"1650398049172","Monitor_SetupWizardActivity_start":"1650398061115","Monitor_SetupWizardActivity_total":"11943","Monitor_SingleFragmentActivity_resumed":"1650398286784","Monitor_SingleFragmentActivity_start":"1650398099736","Monitor_SingleFragmentActivity_total":"19515","ObjectivesActionsUsed":"true","Objectives_auto_accomplished":"0","Objectives_auto_started":"0","Objectives_autosens_accomplished":"0","Objectives_autosens_started":"0","Objectives_config_accomplished":"0","Objectives_config_started":"0","Objectives_exam_accomplished":"0","Objectives_exam_started":"0","Objectives_maxbasal_accomplished":"0","Objectives_maxbasal_started":"0","Objectives_maxiob_accomplished":"0","Objectives_maxiob_started":"0","Objectives_maxiobzero_accomplished":"0","Objectives_maxiobzero_started":"0","Objectives_openloop_accomplished":"0","Objectives_openloop_started":"0","Objectives_smb_accomplished":"0","Objectives_smb_started":"0","Objectives_usage_accomplished":"0","Objectives_usage_started":"0","absorption_cutoff":"6","activity_duration":"0","activity_target":"0","age":"adult","always_use_shortavg":"false","application_protection":"0","aps_mode":"open","autosens_max":"1.2","autosens_min":"0.7","bolus_protection":"0","boluswizard_percentage":"100","bt_watchdog":"false","carbsReqThreshold":"1","carbs_button_increment_1":"5","carbs_button_increment_2":"10","carbs_button_increment_3":"20","dexcom_lognssensorchange":"false","dexcomg5_nsupload":"false","dexcomg5_xdripupload":"false","eatingsoon_duration":"0","eatingsoon_target":"0","enableSMB_after_carbs":"false","enableSMB_always":"false","enableSMB_with_COB":"false","enableSMB_with_high_temptarget":"false","enableSMB_with_temptarget":"false","enable_carbs_required_alert_local":"true","enable_fabric2":"true","enable_missed_bg_readings":"false","enable_pump_unreachable_alert":"true","fill_button1":"0.3","fill_button2":"0","fill_button3":"0","gradually_increase_notification_volume":"false","high_mark":"0","high_temptarget_raises_sensitivity":"false","hypo_duration":"0","hypo_target":"0","insulin_button_increment_1":"0.5","insulin_button_increment_2":"1.0","insulin_button_increment_3":"2.0","keep_screen_on":"false","key_usersuperbolus":"false","language":"default","last_revoked_certs_check":"1650398043316","last_time_this_version_detected":"1650398061747","last_versionchecker_plugin_waring":"1650398048275","loop_openmode_min_change":"20","low_mark":"0","low_temptarget_lowers_sensitivity":"false","maintenance_logs_amount":"2","maintenance_logs_email":"logs@androidaps.org","master_password":"hmac:1067c3e86cb042d799eb25e9988280703563366195f38dee2d6f1f5cc05f57e6:7b29002999b3af7dd1e5fb0b2f3f4ea96ad90a410549bf0c6e34bc9ff5e5039c","missed_bg_readings_threshold":"30","nextMissedReadingsAlarm":"1650398347880","nextPumpDisconnectedAlarm":"1650398347880","ns_alarms":"false","ns_announcements":"false","openapsama_current_basal_safety_multiplier":"4","openapsama_max_daily_safety_multiplier":"3","openapsama_min_5m_carbimpact":"8.0","openapsama_useautosens":"false","openapsma_max_basal":"1","openapsmb_max_iob":"3","pump_unreachable_threshold":"30","raise_urgent_alarms_as_android_notification":"true","resistance_lowers_target":"false","sensitivity_raises_target":"true","settings_protection":"0","short_tabtitles":"false","show_calibration_button":"true","show_carbs_button":"true","show_cgm_button":"false","show_insulin_button":"true","show_notes_entry_dialogs":"false","show_statuslights":"true","show_treatment_button":"false","show_wizard_button":"true","smbinterval":"3","smbmaxminutes":"30","smscommunicator_otp_secret":"Qz12f1m7s5Tt8Q37ZB3FYFQS9ef1p3oxtYy+t9oTQ90","startupwizard_processed":"true","statuslights_bage_critical":"240","statuslights_bage_warning":"216","statuslights_bat_critical":"5","statuslights_bat_warning":"25","statuslights_cage_critical":"72","statuslights_cage_warning":"48","statuslights_iage_critical":"144","statuslights_iage_warning":"72","statuslights_res_critical":"10","statuslights_res_warning":"80","statuslights_sage_critical":"240","statuslights_sage_warning":"216","statuslights_sbat_critical":"5","statuslights_sbat_warning":"25","treatmentssafety_maxbolus":"3","treatmentssafety_maxcarbs":"48","uamsmbmaxminutes":"30","units":"mg\/dl","use_bolus_advisor":"false","use_bolus_reminder":"false","use_smb":"false","use_uam":"false","virtualpump_type":"1","virtualpump_uploadstatus":"false"}
```

using the posted test data.

---

Note that the size of the nonce should be known on both sides so that the size doesn't need to be stored.
Also, for security reasons, the (non-secret) salt should be randomly generated like the nonce and passed to the decryption side concatenated, e.g. `salt|nonce|ciphertext|tag`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I ran with my inputs and got `ValueError('MAC check failed'), <traceback object at 0x10b13cd40>)`.

Comment: Seems to happen on line `decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(actualCiphertext, tag)`

Comment: I confirmed with one of the developers this function is used to generate my file. I will dig deeper. I have a compiled app that I can generate another file with to confirm passphrase. Here is a sample of my cypher text `"content": "DDKzZYxtcKt6\/WCcU73oe3EsJnyTzZSdgzEARpYMGiUdTY...` it seems escaped.

Comment: It's json. I'm grabbing the value for my ciphertext text example with `content = data['content']`

Comment: @square_eyes - From my point of view the question is answered: A ciphertext generated with the encrypt() method of the Kotlin code can be decrypted with the decrypt() method of the Python (or Kotlin) code, see test case. If you think that this is not the case, post corresponding test data that proves that. The information in this question simply does not allow for a deeper analysis of why your *particular* data is not decryptable.

Comment: It works! Thank you for sticking with me. `bytes.fromhex()` on the salt did the trick.